# Using angular services before manual bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to use angular services before doing a manual bootstrap(the ng-app directive is not being used).  Is there a way to access angular services without calling angular.bootstrap on an empty div?

The following approach works, but I'm wondering if there is a more direct solution:

```
  var element = angular.element('<div></div>');
  angular.bootstrap(element);
  var $injector = element.injector();
  var $http = $injector.get('$http');
  var $location = $injector.get('$location');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a way to do it without calling bootstrap (or getting the injector from an already bootstrapped element), but there is a slightly more direct way of doing it:

```
var $http = angular.bootstrap().get('$http');
```

Or, if you need multiple services, you can do this:

```
angular.bootstrap().invoke(function($http, $location){ 
    $http.get('/foo');
    $location.path('/foo');
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  I hadn't looked at invoke or the fact that bootstrap returns the injector, very helpful.  Playing around some more, it looks like angular.bootstrap() works fine with no arguments.

Comment: Cool.  I've updated my answer.  I thought I had tried that and got an error, but I tried again and it worked, so I was mistaken.