# ExpressJS variables in AngularJS - Mean Stack

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, mean-stack

I am building a MEAN application, one issue I have is that I want to give my users some sort of control over the routes used. So I want my server side code (expressJS) to set some variables in my client side code.

Essentially I want to be able to generate my client side JS from my server side code.

for example, in PHP I would probably do something along the lines of

```
<?php
echo <script>
echo  var test = $test
echo </script>
 ?>
```

I am not talking about binding, the variables only need to be set at the initial application load.

What would be the best way to accomplish this kind of integration with MEAN, in the cleanest way possible...

Comment: You could write an object server side and than request it in the static way.Sorry I'm busy at moment to do a working example just the idea ^^

Comment: as in grab it with ajax?

Comment: No, you load it by express like a static file, you write the js file than you request it in the jade template

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698534/how-to-pass-variable-from-jade-template-file-to-a-script-file it's not  my idea but ..

Comment: I open an other thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21401998/jade-how-to-write-script-tag-with-server-side-value

Answer (score 4):

Just an other approch

```
router.js
app.get('/myconfig', function(req, res){
    var config = {prop1:1,myarray:[1,2,3]};
    var json = JSON.stringify(config);
    res.end('var config='+json);
});
jade
script(type='text/javascript', src='/myconfig')
```

than in angular you can do

```
angular.module('yourApp').constant('setup', config)
```

Comment: maybe you should set `res.set('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');`

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**

First write an api endpoint that will return your configurations.

```
app.get('/conf', function(req, res) {
    res.send(200, {
        foo: "bar"
    });
});
```

Then do a `$http.get` to this endpoint and retrieve the configuration object on angular `app.run` and store this configuration in a service/`$rootScope`/config.

`app.run` is the closest thing in angular to a `main()` function and will run once when the application starts.

**Option 2**

Use [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

If your solution does not need to explicitly get the variables from server side, and if they are known at the time you deploy the application, you can do a javascript compile and inject the configurations using grunt.

This is how I have personally handled this situation.

Answer (score 1):

#### My approach is a complete separation between client & server side.

A demo plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/5cFLo3wLfbL0bUnifJe5?p=preview

**The server should only be concerned with resources:**

```
app.get('/api/setup', function(req,res){

  var setup = // something

  res.json(setup);
})
```

**The client can defer bootstrap after fetching data:**

Based on this answer: [Using angular services before manual bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365084/using-angular-services-before-manual-bootstrap#20365360)

```
angular.bootstrap().invoke(function($http){ 

    $http.get('/api/setup').then(function(res){

        // providing the fetched data to the module:
        angular.module('yourApp').constant('setup', res.data)

        // manual bootstraping
        angular.bootstrap(document,['yourApp']);

    })
});
```

**Then you can inject `setup` inside your module:**

```
app.config(function(setup){
  // constants can be injected to config blocks
})

app.controller('ctrl',function(setup){
   // do what you need
})
```

**If you need a splash screen check my answer:** [Creating a splash screen using ng-cloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294917/creating-a-splash-screen-using-ng-cloak/21295787#21295787)

Comment: Thanks Ilan, when you say setup can be injected anywhere does that include config and/or run blocks in angular?

Comment: a **value provider** can be injected to run blocks/controllers/directives/services/etc but not to config blocks. If you need to inject it to config blocks then use a **constant provider** instead of a **value provider**. Check this: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.$provide#methods_constant

Comment: All in all I'm wondering if there is a way to write the config by jade doing like script= config

Comment: Are you sure to have the config ready when the ctrl is called ?

Comment: Yes, the controller would not be called before `angular.bootstrap(document,['yourApp']);` and at that point we have already declared the config as a service. just to be sure you must omit `ngApp` directive.