# How to pass data from EJS template to AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, ejs

I've got the user data from ExpressJS through NodeJS as following:

**app.js**

```
app.get('/user', function(req, res) {
    res.render('users', { title: 'Foo', user: req.user });
});
```

**users.ejs**

```
<%= user %>
```

I need the `user` data from `user.ejs` above to an angularjs controller, so I could display that on other named views.

Could somebody help me with it?

Comment: see http://www.mircozeiss.com/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-from-a-server-to-angular/ & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399482/expressjs-variables-in-angularjs-mean-stack

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some say **ng-init** but it just feels dirty and wrong to me. You can put it inline and mess with the window and **rootscope** but it can get messy. Or you can inline another **module** like:

```
<script>
   angular.module('PreloadedData', [])
     .constant('User', <%- user %>);
</script>
```

Then it will be available like any other dependency.

Comment: The following code works: `var user = <%- JSON.stringify(user) %>; angular.module('PreloadedData', [])
     .constant('User', user);`

Comment: looks hacky but me likey

Answer (score 0):

```
try this on template...

<% if(title){ %>
 <script>
window.Mytitle = <%- JSON.stringify(title) %>;
</sript>
<% } %>

try on your controller..
console.log(window.Mytitle);
```

================================================

```
try this on template...

<% if(user){ %>
<script>
  window.MyUser = {};
  window.MyUser = <%- JSON.stringify(user) %>;
</sript>
<% } %>

try on your controller..
console.log(window.MyUser);
```

sorry if am wrong..