# Doing away with Angular deferredbootstrapper

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to bypass the angular deferredbootstrapper for the standard application initialize.

Am I supposed to invoke the app with this injector module method? docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector

[Rewriting Angular.js app to do away with deferredBootstrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103536/rewriting-angular-js-app-to-do-away-with-deferredbootstrapper/27108691#27108691)

getting errors like

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ECP due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $http

Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'Nav' is not a function, got undefined

--- not sure how to include the previous injectorModules
--- or tap into the Account and User variables to stash information before other modules are loaded

```
app.config(["$http", "$q", "Account", "Layout",
      function ($http, $q, Account, Layout) {
```

Seems like the wrong way to do it. To me it looks similar to how a directive is setup.

Comment: only serviceProvider can be inject in the config block

Comment: I see. What would be the solution to this problem? Of loading the modules and configuring in such a way without the deferredbootstrapper

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the link I don't use requirejs.

Comment: Any suggestions from anyone. I am more of a visulization developer - so I am a bit stumped on this - but this is the task that has been assigned to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using angular services before manual bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365084/using-angular-services-before-manual-bootstrap)